# Software to keymap between mac and rhel - swap the control and command key

Tags: macos, keyboard, rhel, rhel7

Is there any good software out there that helps with keyboard mapping for Mac keyboards so they can be used easily on RHEL specifically swapping out the control and the command key
to make basic copy paste operations super simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here. Its pretty straightforward :

1. run the following command to get a list of all keymaps :

`localectl list-keymaps | grep mac`

2. run the following command to set a keymap like for english mac :

`localectl set-keymap mac-us`

https://linuxthegreat.wordpress.com/2017/03/11/changing-the-keyboard-layout-rhel-7/